# How to select values inside list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

How to select values inside MultiSelect? I just want to select some items inside a dropdownlist from URL Variables

**Issue:** following line is not selecting items `Colors.add(TempArray[i]);`

**debug:** If I remove this line than it works ok and selects values. `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) ... foreach (var item2 in TempArray)` but I need this line to check for null values. Code will get error otherwise

Also If I remove `Post` Method and it goes to `Get` directly than it works fine (items get selected). how can I make it work by using post method

Form

```
<form asp-page="./Index" method="post">
<select asp-for="Colors" asp-items="@Model.Colors_SELECT " class="MultiSelect" multiple>
     ....
</select>
...
```

back-end variables

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public List<string>? Colors { get; set; }
public SelectList? Colors_SELECT { get; set; }
```

OnPost() Method - here I am change the URL format. for ex: `localhost/index?Colors=red&Colors=Black` to `localhost/index?Colors=red,Black`

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var CurrentFilters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var ColorsTemp = string.Join(",", Colors);
        CurrentFilters.Add("Colors", ColorsTemp);

        string query = "";
        foreach (var p in CurrentFilters)
        {
            query += $"{p.Key}={p.Value}&";
        }
        query = query.TrimEnd(query[query.Length - 1]); //remove last '&' 
        var url = $"{HttpContext.Request.Path}?{query}"; // create URL 
        return Redirect(url); // Send new url - call get Method()
    }
```

on OnGet() method

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    // here i want to get URL values and select those items
    string result = Request.Query["Colors"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        string[] TempArray = result.Split(",");
         foreach (var item2 in TempArray)
         {
             Colors.add(TempArray[i]);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the selected values by the backend ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to add more detail. I am not sure why my code is not selecting items on line `Colors.add(TempArray[i]);`

Comment: How about  using MultiSelectList to display the selected values?

Comment: @QingGuo If i remove `Post` Method and it goes to `Get` directly than it works fine (items get selected).